# Can I tell with adb getprop if device is connected by wifi or usb?

Tags: android, adb

**What property should one use in 'adb getprop' to discriminate between wifi and usb connection?** Is it even possible at all?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean connected to internet (so USB means tethering) or the adb connection?

Comment: @Robert, adb connection for debugging. I want to discriminate between "wifi adb" and "usb adb". I realized just now that "adb get-devpath" gives a string wich seems to give this info... not sure how reliable however.